# How to refactor a SQL query with multiple OR statements for better performance?

Tags: sql, mariadb, query-optimization, hql, where-clause

Using MariaDB.

The query is the following:

```
select  * from table    
where  id > 0  and
( code_field = :code1 and date_field = date(:date1) )  or  
( code_field = :code2 and date_field = date(:date2) )  or  
( code_field = :code3 and date_field = date(:date3) )  or  
...................................................... -- a few thousands combinations  
( code_field = :codeX and date_field = date(:dateX) )
```

Refactoring using the `IN` clause is not an option, since it does result to a Cartesian product.

```
select  * from table    
where  id > 0  and
code_field in (:code1, :code2) and
date_field in (:date1, :date2)
```

Is there a way, either with native SQL or with HQL to improve this query?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: How have you indexed your table?  And if you haven't, then that's where to start.  See https://use-the-index-luke.com/. You probably want an index on code_field+date_field.

Comment: Sometimes it's faster to load those rows into a table first and then join.

Comment: @jarlh MariaDB.

Comment: @AndyLester Apart from the index on the Primary key, I do have a Unique Key on code_field+date_field and its relevant index, is there a way to exploit that or it's just going to help Hibernate to execute the queries faster?

Comment: @dnoeth You mean on a temp table that I will crate on the fly or programmatically? I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: @ChristosKarapapas We're past the point where we can talk in the abstract. We need to see specifics about your table and the actual query you're using.

Comment: What version of MariaDB?

Comment: @RickJames `10.2.23-MariaDB` Do you think it would be faster to manually execute native queries this way, https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-quickly-insert-data-into-mariadb/#inserting-data-into-several-tables-at-once , instead of using Hiberanate's methods for merging? I'm dealing with a parent-child pair of tables that are bidirectionally mapped with Hibernate.

Comment: I don't know anything about Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB understands tuple equality, so you could write the conditions as:

```
where 
    id > 0 
    and (code_field, date_field) in (
        (:code1, date(:date1)),
        (:code2, date(:date2)),
        (:code3, date(:date3)),
        ...
        (:codeN, date(:dateN))
    )
```

This might take advantage of an index on `(code_field, date_field, id)`.

Comment: Great answer! Using tuple equality, for the same amount of combinations, the query ran in less than half of the time.